# React | How to change the style of an element using useRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change an element position base on the mouse position.
I have a list of images displayed in a line using flex and I want to move the container (track) to the right when the mouse is moved to the left.

For this, I want to change the track style but I find it difficult.
I tried using

```js
navTrack.current.transform = `translateX(${-x})`;
```

but it throws an error.

This is the function:

```js
const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
  const x = e.clientX;
  console.log(x);
  navTrack.current.transform = `translateX(${-x})`;
};
```

The function is called on onMouseMove.

Comment: `but it throus an error.` What is the error?

Comment: Are you translating it by Y on purpose? You're getting the X of the mouse, so I'm concerned that you've accidentally typo'ed that.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. I fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may run into issues with this approach and when working in React it is generally recommended to not directly manipulate the DOM if you don't have to (and in this case, you don't). Instead you should do this in a React-like way. You do this by storing the mouse position in state and using it to set the transform property through the `style` prop.

For example, here's a hook that would do this:

```
function useMouseMove() {
    const [mouseX, setMouseX] = React.useState(0);

    const onMouseMove = React.useCallback((e) => {
        setMouseX(e.clientX);
    }, []);

    return { mouseX, onMouseMove };
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
    const { mouseX, onMouseMove } = useMouseMove();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)
    }, [onMouseMove]);

    return (
        <div style={{transform: `translateY(${-mouseX}px)`}}></div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `px` after you interpolate `-mouseX`.

Comment: Thank you! this was great! I extended this hook and used it in other parts of my projects.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `style` property of the element when you want to add CSS. So in your case it would be:

```
navTrack.current.style.transform = `translateY(${-x})`;
```