# React Ref is not updating the CSS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, sass, ref

Needed to update the transform translate CSS of my `imgTrack`, but can't directly change it in react, was trying multiple ways to do so but, the transform property never updates(or it seems so).

To do so I created a function to measure the distance traveled when the mouse is pressed down, converted it to a percentage, and then tried to use this percentage to update the transform values.

You can check out the implemented sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-tdd-vnu3b9?file=/src/projects.scss)

Here is the base code for the same

```js
const [mouseDownAt, setMouseDownAt] = useState(0);
    const [prevPercentage, setPrevPercentage] = useState(0);
    const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(0);
    const imgTrackRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const track = imgTrackRef.current;
        window.onmousedown = function (e) {
            setMouseDownAt(e.clientX);
        };
        window.onmousemove = function (e) {
            if (mouseDownAt === 0) return;
            const mouseDelta = mouseDownAt - e.clientX,
            maxDelta = window.innerWidth / 2;
            const percentage = (mouseDelta / maxDelta) * -100,
                nextPercentage = prevPercentage + percentage;
            setPercentage(nextPercentage);
            track.style.transform = `translateX(${nextPercentage}%, -50%)`
        };
        window.onmouseup = function () {
            setMouseDownAt(0);
            setPrevPercentage(percentage);
        };
        console.log("mouseDownAt: ", mouseDownAt);
        console.log("prevPercentage: ", prevPercentage);
        console.log("percentage: ", percentage);
    }, [ mouseDownAt, prevPercentage, percentage]);
```

as for the render part

```js
<div id="imgTrack" ref = {imgTrackRef}>
   <img className='image' src="" draggable="false" />
   <img className='image' src="" draggable="false" />
   <img className='image' src="" draggable="false" />
</div>
```

I tried storing the values in states and then using it along with ref, but none of it worked.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React | How to change the style of an element using useRef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74281366/react-how-to-change-the-style-of-an-element-using-useref)

Comment: No, but thanks for commenting. As for me, the problem is CSS not being updated even after the correct values are being passed onto it, so I thought there would be something wrong with my refs.

Answer (score 0):

Your style is not updating because your `onmousemove` event listener function `always` gets `0` as a value for all of your state variables. This happens due to **[closures in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)**. The event listener function is created after the component mounts for the first time & at that time all your state variable values are `0`.

> To get the `updated value` for all state variables you need to use [useRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). The idea is you create `a ref` for `each` state variable and keep the `ref's current` value updated on each re-render. `Refs` in React.js are `mutable`, so the value changes but the `reference` doesn't change. Because of this you will be able to get the `updated` value inside your `DOM event listener`.

#### Solution

```js
const [mouseDownAt, setMouseDownAt] = useState(0);
const [prevPercentage, setPrevPercentage] = useState(0);
const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(0);
const imgTrackRef = useRef(null);

const mouseDownAtRef = useRef(mouseDownAt);
const prevPercentageRef = useRef(prevPercentage);
const percentageRef = useRef(percentage);

// update the value of the refs each time the
// component rerenders due to state update
mouseDownAtRef.current = mouseDownAt;
prevPercentageRef.current = prevPercentage;
percentageRef.current = percentage;

useEffect(() => {
  const track = imgTrackRef.current;
  window.onmousedown = function (e) {
    setMouseDownAt(e.clientX);
  };
  window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    if (mouseDownAtRef.current === 0) return;
    const mouseDelta = mouseDownAtRef.current - e.clientX,
      maxDelta = window.innerWidth / 2;
    const percentage = (mouseDelta / maxDelta) * -100,
      nextPercentage = prevPercentageRef.current + percentage;
    setPercentage(nextPercentage);
    track.style.transform = `translateX(${nextPercentage}%, -50%)`;
  };
  window.onmouseup = function () {
    setMouseDownAt(0);
    setPrevPercentage(percentage);
  };
}, [mouseDownAt, prevPercentage, percentage]);
```

**`Updated Project.jsx` file for your code-sandbox**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import { motion, useIsPresent } from "framer-motion";
import "./projects.scss";

function Projects() {
  const isPresent = useIsPresent();
  const container = {
    visible: {
      transition: {
        staggerChildren: 0.1,
        delayChildren: 1
      }
    }
  };

  const [mouseDownAt, setMouseDownAt] = useState(0);
  const [prevPercentage, setPrevPercentage] = useState(0);
  const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(0);
  const imgTrackRef = useRef(null);

  const mouseDownAtRef = useRef(mouseDownAt);
  const prevPercentageRef = useRef(prevPercentage);
  const percentageRef = useRef(percentage);

  // update the value of the refs each time the
  // component rerenders due to state update
  mouseDownAtRef.current = mouseDownAt;
  prevPercentageRef.current = prevPercentage;
  percentageRef.current = percentage;

  useEffect(() => {
    const track = imgTrackRef.current;
    window.onmousedown = function (e) {
      setMouseDownAt(e.clientX);
      console.log("mousedown: ", e.clientX);
    };
    window.onmousemove = function (e) {
      if (mouseDownAtRef.current === 0) return;
      console.log("mousemove: ", mouseDownAtRef.current);
      const mouseDelta = mouseDownAtRef.current - e.clientX,
        maxDelta = window.innerWidth / 2;
      const percentage = (mouseDelta / maxDelta) * -100,
        nextPercentage = prevPercentageRef.current + percentage;
      setPercentage(nextPercentage);
      track.style.transform = `translateX(${nextPercentage}%, -50%)`;
    };
    window.onmouseup = function () {
      setMouseDownAt(0);
      setPrevPercentage(percentage);
      console.log("mouseup: ", percentage);
    };

    console.log();
  }, [mouseDownAt, prevPercentage, percentage]);

  return (
    <>
      <motion.div
        ref={imgTrackRef}
        className="projectsWrapper"
        initial={{ x: 712 }}
        animate={{ x: 0 }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.7, type: "spring", stiffness: 60 }}
        style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}
      >
        <div
          id="imgTrack"
          style={{ transform: `translate(${-percentage}%, -50%)` }}
        >
          <img
            className="image"
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507830940122-38f2fbc6abdd?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=685&q=80"
            alt="Huffman_compressor"
            draggable="false"
          />
          <img
            className="image"
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565789623612-5d58a09e0a28?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1326&q=80"
            alt="flavours_of_youth"
            draggable="false"
          />
          <img
            className="image"
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601379342258-6f1e994c575c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80"
            alt="savourly"
            draggable="false"
          />
          <img
            className="image"
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593873964743-0d8b01c5c09f?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80"
            alt="fier_v1"
            draggable="false"
          />
          <img
            className="image"
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472851294608-062f824d29cc?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80"
            alt="prodigi"
            draggable="false"
          />
          <img
            className="image"
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510146758428-e5e4b17b8b6a?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80"
            alt="teamio"
            draggable="false"
          />
        </div>
      </motion.div>

      <motion.div
        initial={{ scaleX: 1 }}
        animate={{ scaleX: 0, transition: { duration: 1, ease: "circOut" } }}
        exit={{ scaleX: 1, transition: { duration: 0.4, ease: "circIn" } }}
        style={{ originX: isPresent ? 0 : 1 }}
        className="privacy-screen"
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default Projects;
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, also the code I mentioned above was able to capture the percentage properly, but it couldn't update the CSS, console logs always showed the correct values.


You can take a look at the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-tdd-vnu3b9?file=/src/projects.scss)

Comment: [@distortionist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16652491/distortionist) I think, I made a `typo` in the solution. Please use `percentage` directly instead of `percentageRef.current` in `onmouseup` event. I altered the variable here & I can see the images are moving after I apply the `ref` to your `motion.div` element. I have updated the `solution` code

Comment: I really appreciate the efforts, upon further looking into the code to find errors, I found that the code did not work because of the ref but rather due to inline CSS
``style={{ transform: `translate(${-percentage}%, -50%)` }} ``
I wanted to use refs to solve the issue as I could use `animate` rather than `track.style.transform ` to make the effects smoother